# What is this calf gym machine called?

Tags: gym, legs, weights, machine, calf

I would like to buy a calf machine like the one on the picture below. When they have adjustable weights and the shoulder pads, does anyone know what they are called then?

[image]

Comment: IDK your circumstances, but just FYI, this is a pretty niche machine with pretty low general utility. If this is for a home gym, this would probably be unreasonably expensive/space-consuming. You can do calf raises with much more general equipment (dumbbells, barbells, kettle bells)

Comment: I don't even know if I'd call this a "niche machine", that might actually over value it. This machine and it's variants are probably the most useless equipment in most weight rooms.

Comment: You can achieve the same with a couple of bricks (with your heals off the side) and some weights.

Comment: This machine in particular is called back pain.

Answer (score 11):

It's called "standing calf raise machine".

Answer (score 7):

Also search for "gastrocnemius press" or "gastrocnemius machine."

But I agree with the other comment, you can usually get 90% of the benefit of this with existing equipment, be it barbells + power racks, or smith machines, or even simply holding weights / kettlebells / dumbbells in your hands as you lift yourself to your toes and back.

Comment: Also would like to add that you can hardly (if it's even possible) increase the size of your calves. The machine is nearly useless, and really just good for training strength, which you can get from just holding heavy stuff like you said